# How to display the '+' sign in output in typesetting situation?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, traditional-form

When I am typing a document I want to include a 'plus' sign in the output cell, e.g. having '+' as the subscript/superscript of a variable, but mathematica doesn't allow me to do that. Are there ways to get around this?

Comment: Output is `ShowStringCharacters->False` so this will do `Subscript[a, "+"]`.

Comment: Or x Shit + Ctrl +_ + +